# Capture unknown magic method calls?

Tags: python

I have a class for which I would like to override a variety of methods such as `__str__`, `__iter__` or `len`. However, the implementation of all of these methods are identical. For example, I might have something like this:

```
def __len__(self):
    return list.__len__(self.do_something())

def __str__(self):
    return str(self.do_something())

def __iter__(self):
    return list.__iter__(self.do_something())

def items(self):
    return (self.do_something()).items()
```

My idea was to capture the methods or magic methods, and call them after performing `do_something` (in a type of wrapper function). Is there a way to do this? Or maybe there are alternative solutions?

Comment: It almost seems like you should be subclassing `list`, but I can't tell without more context.

Comment: @Stephen S, I am making an object that acts as a remote procedure calling stub. It can be a list, dict, or other object reference (on the server side). The `do_something` method would return the list, if it is a list. However, if it is a dict, it will return a dict. (Forgive my `__iter__` example which simply returns a `list` method)

Comment: @StephenS if I were to subclass `list`, how can I wrap all `list` specific methods?

Comment: If you subclass `list`, it will give you all of the methods of list. Each method that you implement in your subclass will override the parent methods. To call the parent methods anyway, [use super](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7806655/7605753).

Comment: @StephenS, I guess that would also work without subclassing list, but my main concern is to ensure coverage of all the methods that are part of list and dict.

Comment: Oh, I guess I misinterpreted - you want to handle all `__ __` methods in one function. Should have read better. I'm not sure how you'd do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to encapsulate all the "magic" methods, you could use a decorator and a metaclass.

```
import functools


def magic_decorator(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        ...
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return func_wrapper


class WrappedMagicMeta(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for k, v in attrs.items():
            if k.startswith('__') and k.endswith('__') and callable(v):
                attrs[k] = magic_decorator(v)

        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class MyCustomObject(metaclass = WrappedMagicMeta):
    pass
```

You would implement whatever functionality you need to impose on `MyCustomObject`'s magic methods inside `func_wrapper`.

---

- [What is a metaclass?](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-metaclass)
- [What is `@functools.wraps`?](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps)